# Uncaught TypeError with my script

Tags: jquery

I need some help, I don't know why in some websites it not error, but some websites it is error show up.

Its show up the error notice in my console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

Any advice is thanks so much.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery( ".pagenav.home .menu > li:first-child a" ).addClass('important_color');
if (jQuery( ".menu-fixedmenu" ).length) {
    jQuery( ".menu-fixedmenu .menu a" ).each(function() {
        var id  = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        var lenght_id  = id.length;//***this line code error***
        if (typeof id !== "undefined" && lenght_id > 2) {
        if(id.search("#") != -1 && id.search("http")){
            jQuery( window ).scroll(function() {

                if(jQuery(id).isOnScreen()){
                    jQuery(id+' h2').removeClass('fadeInDown');
                    jQuery(id+' h2').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
                    var newid = id.split("#");
                    if(document.getElementById(newid[1]).getBoundingClientRect().top < 250){
                        jQuery( ".fixedmenu .menu > li a[href='"+id+"']" ).addClass('important_color');
                        }

                    else{
                        jQuery( ".fixedmenu .menu > li a[href='"+id+"']" ).removeClass('important_color');
                    }

                }
                else{
                    if(id != jQuery( ".menu > li:first-child a" ).attr('href') )
                        jQuery( ".fixedmenu .menu > li a[href='"+id+"']" ).removeClass('important_color');
                        if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 700)
                            jQuery( ".menu-fixedmenu .menu > li:first-child a" ).removeClass('important_color');
                        else
                            jQuery( ".menu-fixedmenu .menu > li:first-child a" ).addClass('important_color');

                        jQuery(id+' h2').removeClass('fadeInUp');
                        jQuery(id+' h2').addClass('animated fadeInDown');
                    }

            });
        }
        }
    });
}
```

});

Comment: A complete example including the HTML to reproduce the error would be helpful.

Comment: If you console log ```this``` from ```var id  = jQuery(this).attr('href');```, what value do you get? You could also use the parameters that come out of your ```each``` function to get the index and the element. The element parameter out of that function would probably give you what you want. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in one of your `.menu-fixedmenu .menu a` elements doesn't have `href` that's why it is throwing an error.

You can do a check if there's an existing `href` value by doing `if (id)`.

e.g.

```
  if(id) {
    var lenght_id = id.length; //***this line code error***
    if (typeof id !== "undefined" && lenght_id > 2) {
      if (id.search("#") != -1 && id.search("http")) {
        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

          if (jQuery(id).isOnScreen()) {
            jQuery(id + ' h2').removeClass('fadeInDown');
            jQuery(id + ' h2').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
            var newid = id.split("#");
            if (document.getElementById(newid[1]).getBoundingClientRect().top < 250) {
              jQuery(".fixedmenu .menu > li a[href='" + id + "']").addClass('important_color');
            } else {
              jQuery(".fixedmenu .menu > li a[href='" + id + "']").removeClass('important_color');
            }

          } else {
            if (id != jQuery(".menu > li:first-child a").attr('href'))
              jQuery(".fixedmenu .menu > li a[href='" + id + "']").removeClass('important_color');
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 700)
              jQuery(".menu-fixedmenu .menu > li:first-child a").removeClass('important_color');
            else
              jQuery(".menu-fixedmenu .menu > li:first-child a").addClass('important_color');

            jQuery(id + ' h2').removeClass('fadeInUp');
            jQuery(id + ' h2').addClass('animated fadeInDown');
          }

        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank so you so much, I had checked again and found my error with your suggest.

Comment: @Loc_rabbirt Great! Glad it helped.